# Inconsistent line endings warning when line endings are consistent

Tags: visual-studio, line-endings

I was opening an auto-generated file in Visual Studio to inspect it, and Visual Studio tells me the line-endings are inconsistent. I know about the difference between LF and CRLF, so I thought I would try making a small change to the generation code to use the proper newline depending on the platform.

I tell Visual Studio not to change it, and I close the file. I open it with Python and take a look at each of the lines with this snippet of code.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    # uses %r so it prints the non-formatted string (so I can see \r and \n)
    print '\n'.join(('%r' % x for x in f.xreadlines()))
```

I take a look at the output, and every line (except for the last) ends with a '\r\n'. The last line has no newline, so it contains only the text.

I also open the file with Emacs and it doesn't auto-detect to use DOS mode, and shows me the ^M character on every line.

Why are the line endings of the file "inconsistent" when I can see that every line is using the same line ending?

Comment: I keep running into this error when trying to checkin files that VS wrote into. My usual solution is to open the file in Notepad++, change the line endings to Unix and back to DOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(answering my own question, but maybe it will help others in the future)

The line endings weren't "inconsistent", but they also weren't valid. With a little look at hexdump, I found in the file the following at the point where a CRLF should be.

```
0d 0d 0a
```

When the file was written out, it must have written the `\r` character twice or potentially, the literal `\r\n` was used and whatever wrote out the file change the `\n` character into a `\r\n` automatically.